# How to do some calculations using fields within a Field Collection field?

Tags: entities

I have a Field Collection field and I'm trying to do the following:

Multiply the value in one field with the value in another field and have the result shown within a third field.

I have tried Mathfield, but it doesn't support Collection Fields.

Is it possible to do this with Computed Field? How? Or would be difficult to write a custom module to do this?

Comment: When do you want  to do this?

Comment: Optimally right when the fields are filled. But also ok, if the calculation is done when the node is saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Computed Field with the following code (change field_1 and field_2 to your actual fields):

In Computed Code (PHP)

```
$field_a = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_1');
$field_b = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_2');
$sum =  $field_a[0]['value'] * $field_b[0]['value'];
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $sum;
```

Display Code (PHP)

```
$display_output = $entity_field_item['value'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using Computed Field.
The sentence 
$sum = 0;
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);
foreach($wrapper->field_FIELDCOLLECTION as $collection) {
$sum += $collection->field_SUBFIELD->value();
}
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $sum;

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was able to solve my problem from the hints I got from answer. How ever the above code did not work for me. I would mark yours as the answer, but that might not be helpful for someone else searching for the same issue.